# Connection Errors After Upgrade to Artful Aardvark

Tags: thunderbird, imap, laserjet

**Greetings,

Immediately upon upgrading my Ubuntu box from Zesty to Artful Aardvark, I have discovered two connection issues that I have been unable to correct: 
All three of my previously accessible IMAP accounts in Thunderbird now fail with this error;**

```
Could not connect to mail server ... The connection was refused
```

*All three of these accounts continue to work properly under Windows and Android using current settings.*

The other connection issue that I am aware of comes from my HP Color LaserJet printer (MFP M277dw). Before the upgrade, I was able to "print to fax" which caused a dialog to pop up requiring phone number of destination. After the upgrade, print jobs are cued in the virtual fax printer as "held" and trying to release them are unsuccessful... no more pop up in which to enter destination fax number.

Notice how I said, "I have discovered two connection issues...?" That is because both issue appeared at the same time (November 16, 2017), after the upgrade, and I assume there are other problems hiding in the OS which will not appear until I try something else. Any ideas?

I have tried disabling any software firewalls included in this new distribution only to discover that it remained disabled since I disabled it in previous versions (I have a hardware firewall so a software one is unnecessary).

Thank you in advance for any advice you may offer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is only part of an answer to my own question...

About Tunderbird mail ... deleting only one of my three IMAP accounts and adding it back in somehow fixed the the other two in addition to the original account. In other words, fixing one made all three work. Strange, but it works for me. Maybe it will work for you.